# On orientation change LoaderManager calls onLoadFinished but list not set

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have been learning about Android Loaders and been trying to implement one with AsyncTaskLoader.

I have been very successful, thus making this even more annoying :P

My onLoadFinished function is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<JSONArray> arg0, JSONArray data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
      mLoadedData = data;
    //Log.d("here","dosomething");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //Log.d("json",mLoadedData.toString());

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("pub_list");
    ((BP_Fragment) f).set_result(mLoadedData);


}
```

The set_result function in my fragment is as follows:

```
public void set_result(JSONArray data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "set result is called..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    Log.d("pubs",data.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i <data.length(); i++){
        Log.d("string","here");
        JSONObject c;
        try {
            c = data.getJSONObject(i);


        String id = c.getString("pid");
        String name = c.getString("name");
        String town = c.getString("town");
        String county = c.getString("county");
        //Double score=c.getDouble(criteria);
        //Log.d("score",score);
        //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        pubs.add(new PubListDetails(id,name,town,county,1.0,"pub"));
        //map.put(TAG_PID, id);
        //map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

        //productsList.add(map);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



     PubListAdapter adapter = new PubListAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), pubs);
     // Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "This is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Ive used the LoaderManager debugger to check the loader is being retained.. it is. I have used the console Log to output my data from within the set_result function - the data is there each orientation change.. I.E everything is being called, and everything is being passed as suggested YET set_adapter only sets the data to the list the first time, no when it is called as a result of a retained loader.

Why? :P I am flummoxed.

THanks

Comment: Did you try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter?

Comment: The data set has not changed it simply hasnt finished loading at the point of rotation. After rotation i see that the load completes but the setListAdapter does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this.

In my loader Activity I was creating a fragment within onCreate in which was contained my list and my set_result function.

Although the loader was being retained successfully when I was recreating my activity on orientation change it was creating another fragment with the same tag instead of using the retained one.

Thus when I called my set_result function, I assume it was finding my initial fragment and setting the list on that.

I am not sure 100% how fragments work when you create two with the same tag - I can only assume that the recreated version was placed on top of my initial one thus hiding it.